# Can I relay all FTP packets to other server without using SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, ftp

First of all, I'm not a native  English speaker so you can feel awkward while reading my question. I hope all of you guys understand my poor English skill

I'm a front-end web developer and I often develop my company web service at both home and my office. Our web service is really old and it's not replaceable so we decided to use FTP when we develop this.

The problem is occurred when I'm at home. I want to deal with my code remotely at home but there is a firewall that blocks every single connections from outside (except HTTP).

I asked them to unblock firewall only for my VPS IP address instead my home IP address because I'm not always at home and my home IP address can be changed.

Now I can access to my company's FTP server through VPS server but I cannot even create connection with my home computer.

I can even connect SSH to companies server through VPS server but I can't run any  commands since they didn't give me any  permissions. So SSH on company server is just for watch file system (or connect mysql server locally).

My question is: Can we 'relay' every FTP packet to destination server to bypass firewall?

let me provide a simple picture to explain what I want to have.

```
Below explains how it works right now:

[HOME] <--(X)--> [COMPANY]
[HOME] <-------> [VPS]
[VPS]  <-------> [COMPANY]

and below is what I want:

[HOME] <---> [VPS] <---> [COMPANY]
```

Can this approach be implemented without open SSH tunnel on `[COMPANY]`?

Comment: OpenSSH (and many alternate SSH clients) offer a SOCKS proxy mode (`-D`) for connection forwarding. Did you consider using it yet?

Comment: +1 for OpenSSH. Or even OpenVPN, Tinc, .. if you're less familiar with SSH tunnels (and considering that thread topic), you could also use some VPN server on your VPS, and clients on your workstations.